# Change detection not working properly

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm using angular4, this is my template

```
<span>My ID:{{ peerId$ | async }}</span>
<span>My ID:{{ peerId }}</span>
```

This is the component code

```
export class AppComponent implements  OnInit {

    peerId: string = 'Guy';
    peerId$: Observable<string>;


    constructor(private store:Store<AppState>) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.peerId$ = this.store.select("peerId") as Observable<string> ;
        this.peerId$.subscribe((peerId:string)=>{
            this.peerId = peerId; // changed from 'guy' to 'blabla' in debug 
            // in template nothing changes 
        });
```

The change in the Dom element is not triggered, unless I focus on some kind of input in the page then change occur.

I've upgraded from angular2 to 4 and still same problem, If I write a simple setTimeout or Observable I can see the change immediately, so I believe the problem is change detection with ngrx/store.

Comment: Where and how do you initialize the store?

Comment: In the module import

Comment: StoreModule.provideStore( {  peerId : peerReducer} , {  peerId : 'Searching...'  })

Comment: in `@NgModule({ imports: [...]})` I assume. That should be fine then.

Comment: I will add that if the store reducer is of type array then change occur, but not if it is string.

Comment: And you're using default change detection strategy?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140050/discussion-between-haddar-macdasi-and-gunter-zochbauer).